# Rises System.ObjectDisposedException when use keyword used with function result

Tags: f#

**hashAlgorithm** returns **SHA1** for example.
When executed **bytesToHash** rises **System.ObjectDisposedException**.

```
let hashAlgorithm : HashAlgorithm =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("HashAlgorithm")
        |> CryptoConfig.CreateFromName :?> HashAlgorithm

let bytesToHash (bytes : byte[]) =
    bytes |>
        use hash = hashAlgorithm
        hash.ComputeHash
```

If I change to

```
use hash = SHA1.Create()
```

then all works fine.

How to change **bytesToHash** function for using **use** keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely the scope of your `use` block.  Try

```
let bytesToHash (bytes:byte[]) =
    use hash = hashAlgorithm
    bytes |> hash.ComputeHash
```

This disposes of the `hash` value after `ComputeHash` has been called and returns a value.  In your code, `hash` is disposed after you create a function value wrapping `ComputeHash` but before it is actually called with the byte array.

Another problem is that you only create the hash algorithm once, but potentially dispose it multiple times, so I'd expect all but the first call to `bytestToHash` to fail.  You can fix this like so:

```
let hashAlgorithm() : HashAlgorithm = ...

let bytesToHash (bytes:byte[]) =
    use hash = hashAlgorithm()
    bytes |> hash.ComputeHash
```